# How to dinamically change a form depending on the user who is filling it

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to show a form or another depending on the user who is using it, I belong to a company who has their own google domain name@company.es, so I save the email of the user who opens the form and then I look in the Spreadsheet which has an user database like this:

```
          Name                    Mail                    Area

      Julia Roberts          js@company.es              First Area
     Anthony Hopkins         ah@company.es              Second Area
        Matt Damon           md@company.es              Third Area
```

so I put a trigger which runs at the opening of the form and I make:

```
if( Area == "First Area"){
    changeAndShowFormForFirst();
}else if(Area == "Second Area"){
    changeAndShowFormForSecond();
}else if(Area == "Third Area"){
    changeAndShowFormForThird();
}
```

but it doesn't matter what user is logged in, it always change the form AFTER the user uses it, not before like I would like.

¿Is it any way to change the content of the form while it is opening?(with the open trigger)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statements syntax is incorrect. You need to use `==` vs `=`. A single `=` assigns a value. `==` checks for equivalency.

try:

```
if( Area == "First Area"){
    changeAndShowFormForFirst();
}else if(Area == "Second Area"){
    changeAndShowFormForSecond();
}else if(Area == "Third Area"){
    changeAndShowFormForThird();
}
```

EDIT:
Scripts do not run in the live form. The only run in/on the form editor. There are possible solutions to your question, but none of them are trivial. I would first recommend watching the Google IO video on the FormApp to get an idea of what it can and cannot do.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38H7WpsTD0M

Comment: I know, the sintax is not right, it's a bad example, it's not the actual code, I will edit it but please answer my question.

Comment: Thanks Spencer! I thought I wouldnt be a trivial thing, I will watch it. Thanks again.